# use requests get page but not source code in python, why? how can i get source code?

Tags: javascript, python

the page url is `www.nenu.edu.cn/intramural/content/news/110.php`
use chrome get source code is not same with use requests.
i use requests.get is

```
u'\r\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">\r\n<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312" />\r\n<title>\u4e1c\u5317\u5e08\u8303\u5927\u5b66</title>\r\n<link href="../../images/nenu_news.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n\r\n<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> window.location ="http://www.nenu.edu.cn/intramural/content/news/110.php";</script>'
```

Comment: Server-side source code is not sent to the browser. For that matter source code for compiled languages is likely not even on the server anyway, only the compiled programs are. Chrome (or any browser or other program that makes an http request) can only view what is actually sent in the response.

Comment: @nnnnnn: I think that's not what he's asking, but I agree that the wording and title of his question are so confusing and badly written (in broken English) that it's hard to see what he's actually after... but that `window.location = ...` definitely seems relevant.

Comment: @ErikAllik - Yes, I took my best guess at what the OP _seemed_ to be asking. If the question was about extracting the `window.location = ...` JS from the response, well, that's not really what I'd call "source code". But from the response to your answer you're obviously right (so +1 on that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look inside the HTML that `requests.get` is giving you, you'll see the following snippet:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
window.location ="http://www.nenu.edu.cn/intramural/content/news/110.php";
</script>
```

What this means is that when Chrome loads the page, that small Javascript code snippet inside the page will tell the browser to navigate to `http://www.nenu.edu.cn/intramural/content/news/110.php`—it is probably the HTML content of that page you are seeing instead when you View Source in Chrome. However, `requests` does not parse and execute Javascript in the response because it's not a browser, so it just gives you the literal response text.

Simple as that.

**EDIT:** actually your question (especially the title) is so badly written (in terms of general clarity as well as your very poor English grammar), that I'm not sure if this was the only thing you were asking, so please try to put more effort into writing your questions in the future.

**PS.** pages that use `window.location = ...` or similar tricks to do redirects are quite difficult to crawl without resorting to using a full browser or browser emulator.

Comment: thanks,if i want spider this page. in python, what should i do?

Comment: @user2606397: also, if I answered your question, please show your gratitude by Accepting it—this is how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: :sorry,i just want know how to  parse and execute js in python, through search maybe i can get it use phantomjs.i am try and say sorry again.

Comment: @user2606397: that is completely different question; if you want to find out how to execute JS in Python (after having extracted it from the HTML), you should create a new question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: ok,thanks,if through my try can not got it.i will ask,i all fell sorry about my English, thank you teach Stackoverflow rulls and give this answer.